# WPF Designer custom initialisation to show example data from database or files during coding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, designer

when i open a XAML with the designer the XAML is partially initialized to show data and formatting.

How can i control how this initialization is done to set up database connections and load test data and initialize styles which are done programatically? I work with vb.net if that makes any difference.

Currently when I open the XAML in the Designer I get error messages because the database connection is not set up at all.

I have tried to do this initialisation before InitializeComponent() in the public sub new of the WPF Window but it does not work.

Iam sorry if this has been answered multiple times already but i failed to find anything partly because I have no idea for what terms to search.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Pro tips : forget about the designer. It works for hello world project IMHO. Once your project starts to use dependency injection, third party control, several DLL, you won't ever use the designer. I disable the splitview in VS to increase perf. If you really need the designer, try to look at DesignTime DataContext. But the time spent isn't worth it as the designer won't work anymore soon or later. You will learn XAML faster ;)

Comment: Hi Nk54. i place things with XAML and only want to use the designer to see how it will look like - to better appease the graphics/ui guys :). But most styles in the application are initialized in code (to better change fontsizes and colors and stuff during runtime compared to a static style file). But yea the applicaton is quite large.. Thx for the search tip. will check that tomorrow.